# Python string to datetime-date

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I've got lots of dates that look like this: `16.8.18` (American: 8/16/18) of type string. Now, I need to check if a date is in the past or future but, `datetime` doesn't support the German format.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: It does if you either set the locale or provide a format...

Comment: Ok but how do I do that?

Comment: `from datetime import datetime as dt; date = dt.strptime(string, format=...)`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand it either. What does the string mean / do?

Comment: See here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior Please try to figure this out.

Comment: I tried: `datetime.strptime(today, format='de_DE')` but then it says: `TypeError: strptime() takes no keyword arguments`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176427/discussion-between-niels-dingsbums-and-coldspeed).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

s = "16.8.18"
d = datetime.strptime(s, "%d.%m.%y")

if d > datetime.now():
    print('Date is in the future.')
else:
    print('Date is in the past.')
```

Prints (today is 20.7.2018):

```
Date is in the future.
```

The format used in `strptime()` is explained in the [manual pages](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).